# Работа с моделям в Django

Tags: python, django

Нужен совет по Моделям Django.
У меня есть Модель описывающая Модель Принтера
Где указан его статус(стоит ли именно тут делать статус или сделать отдельную таблицу скажем "Журнал принтеров") Есть модель "Заявка" где указывается номер заявки описание и серийный номер принтера(выберается из списка) Вопрос: Когда заявка формируется необходимо что бы менялся статус принтера.
Подскажите как это можно реализовать.

Comment: что должно произойти с принтером, если он попал в заявку?

Comment: изменится статус "На ремонт"

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону ForeignKey. Через него надо будет связать заявки и принтеры может сработает. Или при создании заявки отправлять запрос к БД на изменение статуса принтера.

Comment: во view, где формируете заявку, измените статус принтера по id, например:

`    printer = Printer.objects.get(id=device_id)
     printer.is_available = False
     printer.save()`

Comment: а если я хочу в админке менять?

Comment: Все модели которые ты создашь, можешь перекинуть в админку. Поле "На ремонт" и "Готов к использ." можешь зазначить булевыми значениями                   -> is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)   . Через него будет проще ловить принтер по id, и проще отображать в темплейтах